# Payoff Function Parisian Option - Does Vector have at least k consecutive entries equal to 1?

Tags: r

I have a problem using the "fOptions" Package for R. While I use the built-in MonteCarloSimulator with it's standard innovations and path generator I change the Payoff Function to price Parisian Options.
My Problem is that the MCSimulation overpices the Option by 0.2.

Now my Question is: Is the Code I wrote correct?
It should do the following (it's part of a function, the other stuff is correct):

1. I get a vector "path", which is constructed from the exponent of a geometric Brownian Motian, so the first line changes this "path" to a vector containing the values of the Underlying.
2. I change path to be a 0-1 Vector containing 1s where the Underlying value falls below the barrier H.
3. I change path to be a True-False Vector containing the information if there are k or more consecutive steps in which the asset is below the barrier H.
4. If this is the case, set payoff to 0.

   ```
   path = S*exp(cumsum(path))
   path = (path <= H) + 0
   path = (rle(path)$values[which(rle(path)$lengths >= k)] == 1)

   if (sum(path) > 0) {payoff = 0}
   ```

The code seems to be wrong for small k = 0, 1, 2, ... as the option prices underestimates the probability of a Knock-Out.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: The path is generated via

```
wienerPath = function(eps) {
path = (b-sigma*sigma/2)*delta.t + sigma*sqrt(delta.t)*eps
path
}
```

where "eps" is a matrix filled with sobol low discrepancy numbers. the matrix which i get by running wienerPath is then inserted in my payoff function row by row, so "path" in the code in my original question is a vector.

Comment: Where does the initial `path` come from? If it is already a geometric  brownian motion, as you write, you should not take the exponential.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I inserted the code as Edit.

Comment: You need to compute the expectation with respect to the risk-neutral measure,
not the physical measure: in concrete terms, it usually means there is no drift. In addition, to have a Brownian motion, you need to integrate the noise, e.g., by replacing `eps` with `cumsum(eps)`. (I assume that your quasi-random numbers are already Gaussian.)

Comment: I pasted the full code here: http://pastebin.com/zuEPNKdJ Maybe you can take a look, I think I calculated the path the correct way. I calculate the paths of the asset tree using the solution of the geom. brownian motion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) with mu being my interest rate and sigma being the volatility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the title question without plowing thru the sample code:

```
foo<-sample(c(0,1),1000,replace=TRUE)
bar<-rle(bar)

bar$values[bar$lengths >=k]
```

If you get any "1"s out of that last line, you win.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Didn't know you could drop the "which()". I'm sorry if I don't understand you correctly, but if I sum over the last line and check if it's bigger than 0, don't I have the result? I'm sorry but my R coding and my english aren't that good.

Comment: @JohnDoe746 Yes, but be careful. If your input is purely ones and zeroes, you can sum the last line.  If there are other values, then you might need to do something like `any(bar$values[bar$lengths >=k] ==1)`

Comment: Okay, thanks. But from `path = (path <= H) + 0` I only get ones and zeroes, right?

Comment: @JohnDoe746  Yes - you don't need to do the `+0` as subsequent functions will coerce the TRUE/FALSE values in `path` to numeric as needed.